# CSS overlapping tabs different widths

Tags: css, tabs, overlapping

I am finding numerous CSS tutorials that are great for overlapping tabs but none of them are with various widths for each tab.  Is it even possible to have the width change based on the size of title?

Here are 3 tabs as examples of how they vary.

**About Us   |   Auto Glass For Your Vehicle   |   Emergency & Business Glass Services**

Note:  The graphic for the tab has shading and will be PNG 24 of course so that it will overlap but I can't imagine how to change width.

Would there be part of the graphic doing a repeat-x?  If so, how would you put the end caps and still be based on active tab?

**EDIT:**  Here is a link showing how each tab is SAME length with a static image for the tab.  I need to figure out how to do the exact same thing but with middle part of tab ability to "grow" in width depending on title of the tab:
http://code-pal.com/examples/how-to-code-an-overlapped-menu/

Comment: I'm confused. It would immensely help if you posted some help or maybe a jsFiddle!

Comment: Could you put up an example of what you've got thus far? Try jsfiddle.

Comment: I added a link in the EDIT field showing the normal way of doing a tab with a static image.  Need ability to repeat-x somehow to grow width as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this tutorial will really help you out. It does overlapping tabs with variable widths exactly like you're asking. It doesn't appear to be infinitely wide, but you just have to adjust the length of the longer sides to be longer than they will need to be.

http://www.codealamode.net/overlapping-tabs

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for.  Brilliant!  I was beginning to think it wasn't possible.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use padding.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 is really long</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    background: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9V8Q6/)

Comment: Thank you.  I do understand how to do it without images.  I need to be able to make the background IMAGE grow in width.  You can't do it with a static image and "stretch" it or it till distort.

Comment: How is the shading? A trick I've used before is to have the image shade into a solid color, and set that color as my background.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you are looking for [Multiple Backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Multiple_backgrounds) supported in CSS3

I am posting a demo soon.

**EDIT:** Another answer was accepted, I am not posting a demo.